# Grounding Wire to copper pipe for cable

Tags: electrical, plumbing, grounding, usa

I'm working on renovating my basement, but first am replacing all of my existing copper pipes with modern CPVC to eliminate the constant leak headache since we are on a well.

Last night I found this wire grounding that appears to be for my cable.

[image]
[image]

Would someone be able to answer a few questions for me?

1. Is this technically out of code?
2. Should this be done external to my home?
3. Since I am removing my copper water lines, what is the alternate replacement for this grounding wire?

Comment: So first of all welcome to StackExchange! First of all do you mean you are replacing the copper with PEX? Secondly to answer your question about grounding, what you show is up to code to attach it to pipes with the clamp style you show. You will have to find new ground locations for anything connected which is a very big project. You can possibly hook it up to some other pipe that goes into the earth or a grounding bar back at your breaker box. A pretty big project to reground the entire house in lack of copper

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that another method of grounding is to use GFCI outlets. They of course cost a bit more than standard outlets but can save the huge effort of regrounding easier. You can link a standard outlet to a GFCI which saves some cost, but do look up the code around doing this. The GFCI + any attached outlets must support the given load

Comment: @EricF I think the ground the poster is discussing is for the cable system signal (TV/internet/phone), not power, so GFCI would not directly help that issue.

Comment: @bib Ohh then I am mistaken if that is what is being asked

Comment: GFCI outlets are useful adjuncts to help prevent electric shock, but **they are not grounding devices**. There is serious danger of electrocution and of damage to appliances if the ground-to-neutral connection is lost!

Comment: that is a lightning arrestor .... it needs to be grounded well

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to answer code questions without knowing where you are.  So, where are you?

Comment: The original poster commented on a downvoted answer that he's in MD.  (I'm assuming that means Maryland, US.)  I'm commenting that here so the information won't be lost if the answer is deleted.

Comment: Can you get to the grounding electrode conductor system, electrical panel, or intersystem bonding termination block for your house from where this CATV ground wire is?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just leave that pipe in place (even if it doesn't carry water?)  That would seem to solve all the problems at once.

Comment: I have a well, and have copper piping that is over 100 years old in places.  No leaks!  (No water softener, either.)

If you have constant leaks in your copper, it might be because of your water quality, but it's not because you have a well.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to see if you could move that connection to a location where you have grounding available easily. That is just a COAX cable, for TV service or internet, via satellite or cable. It can be mounted anywhere along the line run, but preferably as close to the beginning of the run, or at least prior to any device connections. The installer found a copper pipe and just grounded there. As for the comment of leave this as is, if you disconnect the pipes before and after, then it is no longer a ground connection.